# How to decide the use of 'sehr' and 'zu' with 'nicht'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonym

Stufe: A1.

Beispiel:

I want to say:

> It is not cold enough.

So, would I say:

> Es ist nicht **sehr** kalt.

or,

> Es ist nicht **zu**  kalt.

I am asking this because we have learnt that 'sehr' is for expressing a positive view and zu is to express negative.

> I want to express disappointment.

Comment: Why do you want to use "sehr" or "zu" in the first place? "A lot of" translates to "viel/viele":  "Er hat nicht viele Bonbons."

Comment: The expression of disappointment was a really important addition in your latest edit. "Einfach nicht kalt genug, heute."

Comment: @tofro  considering that, the English original sentence *It's not too cold* already fails to express disappointment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking your edit into account, I have the impression that you're looking for "genug". So here is the full picture:

(Not) to a high degree, neutral attitude:

> *Es ist sehr kalt.* = *It's very cold.*
>
> *Es ist nicht sehr kalt.* = *It's not very cold.*

(Not) more than desired:

> *Es ist zu kalt.* = *It's too cold* (for swimming in the lake).
>
> *Es ist nicht zu kalt.* = *It's not too cold* (for swimming in the lake).

(Not) sufficient, (not) as much as desired:

> *Es ist kalt genug.* = *It's cold enough* (for ice-skating).
>
> *Es ist nicht kalt genug.* = *It's not cold enough* (for ice-skating).

Comment: "Very many" ist Denglish....

Comment: And "not very many" isn't